# Is Legoland only for kids?

Tags: children, denmark, amusement-parks

We're planning a trip somewhere with my family.
My brother is 12 and I'm 18 (and childish).

We thought Legoland Billund could be a nice place to visit, and the flights are cheap too.
But our father disagrees, and says it's only for 12 year old kids.

Here in Finland, the craziest rides go about up to 80km/h, so compared to that, how crazy are the best rides there?

Is it so, or can even the parents enjoy the visit?

Comment: I don't think there is any age anyway. Lego dates from a generation that is not young any more. But I think this is also not a matter to be discussed here. You can try to post on http://bricks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Lego and may be asked on [Lego Answers](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nah, I'm asking is the place itself entertaining for older people or just kids?

Comment: mmh I would say it is a quite subjective question. What do you mean by "parents enjoying it". I enjoy playing with Lego, even if I am older than 12. It just depends on what parents like.

Comment: I'm not talking about the Lego theme only. Is the place designed for kids only? Are the rides fast enough for older people than 12 year olds?

Comment: I have not been to a Lego park myself, but I can say that any theme park will have activities/attractions for adults. Children cannot take themselves to these parks and so adults will always be present. Major theme parks know this and cater to adults as well as children. As far as rides are concerned, I do not know, but there will definitely be some sort of aspect of the park geared towards adults.

Comment: According to my 5 year old nephew, the Lego *movie* is only for Kids.  Not sure that helps for your question, but he was fairly adamant about it so I though I'd mention it... :)

Comment: @Vince I gather from your comments that there might be some confusion: The question is not about playing Lego, it's about a theme park.

Comment: @Doc are you my long lost twin?!  =O  Putting that aside, as I hear tell, the Lego movie is quite entertaining to people of all ages.  I haven't gotten around to seeing it yet but many of my friends (ages 25-36) have and enjoyed it immensely.

Comment: @Doc Me and my brother **really** enjoyed the Lego Movie.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it helps, two couples I know, both in their early 30s went a couple of years ago (to the one in the UK).  One especially is lego mad, and everyone loved it.

Evidently the place is arranged at different levels. So while kids might just enjoy that it's Lego, adults can engage in the hunts, the themes and more.

A [review of some of the rides](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g186419-i1323-k3070945-Legoland_for_adults-Windsor_Windsor_and_Maidenhead_Berkshire_England.html) of the UK one points out that yes, 2/3 of the park is aimed at children, but adults will still enjoy many aspects of it, as will a teenager like yourself.

I guess it comes down to how much you like Lego.  If you're fine being a big kid, like many adults I know, you'll love it.  If you're the self-conscious 'must be cool' type, you might get bored.

Comment: I'm sure I'll love it, but my dad might just be a little too grown up.

Comment: @Claudio I'd be amazed if there wasn't stuff for unchildish adults: there's a whole subculture of Lego-obsessed adults who take themselves ***very*** seriously, using Lego for engineering/art type projects that are often genuinely impressive ([example 1](http://mathmomblog.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/incredible-lego-mindstorms-creation-a-lego-car-factory/), [example 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GH4clQJ3VuA#t=10)). Lego inc are very much in touch with that community and I'd be very surprised if there weren't whole sections of Legoland geared towards that sort of thing.

Answer (score 12):

The "craziest" rides in Legoland Denmark are:

- [Polar X-plorer](http://www.legoland.dk/en/Explore/Activities/Polar-Land/Polar-X-plorer/). Top speed of 65 km/h, 16m drop;
- [X-treme Racers](http://www.legoland.dk/en/Explore/Activities/Adventure-Land/X-treme-Racers/). Top speed of 60km/h, also 16m drop;
- [Ice Pilots School](http://www.legoland.dk/en/Explore/Activities/Polar-Land/Ice-Pilots-School/), quite unique experience of being on a shaker ;-)

[Rest of the rides](http://www.legoland.dk/en/Explore/Activities/) are quite soft. I've enjoyed Legoland as relaxed family holiday. Indeed I feel that the park is best suited for families with kids 2-10 y/o. If it's crazy rides you're looking for, you're probably going to be disappointed. There are theme parks that are much better for that. In that case you'd be much better off going to [Europa-Park](http://www.europapark.de/) or [PortAventura](http://www.portaventura.co.uk/).

Comment: This makes me question the trip. But provides a different point of view to this.

Comment: @Claudio If the only thing about a theme park (or park in general) that is 'fun' is fast rides and scary roller coasters, then Legoland is probably not your best choice.  If, however, you also enjoy seeing pretty awesome sites and the less heart-throbbing rides then you'll likely be quite happy at Legoland.

Comment: @Doc I actually don't like the really fast rides, as long as the place has a decent roller coaster.

Answer (score 9):

I went to the German LEGOLAND near Augsburg last September with my 4 children (21, 18, 13, 6). It was a day out together. We have all played with lego in the past but none of us are 'lego nerds'. The park was nice, the models well done and there are some nice rides. However, all in all, I would say that the age limit is around 12-13. My older ones didn't complain but I could only see enthusiasm in the youngest one. A large proportion of the visitors seemed to be grandparents with their grandchildren which I guess is exactly who Lego are targeting. The most annoying thing by a long way was the continuous background musak- terrible, terrible, terrible! There was no escape anywhere.

It was ok but I won't be rushing back.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a precedent set for Legoland [denying entry to a senior who tried to visit without being accompanied by a young child](http://news.nationalpost.com/2013/07/09/lego-loving-senior-citizen-learns-he-isnt-welcome-at-legoland-unless-he-brings-kids/).  (This was at a Legoland Discovery Centre in Ontario, not a Legoland amusement park.)

Comment: Interesting story, but not quite related.